# Curious bug (?) of HTML5 canvas rendering rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas to pre-render sprites and have come across some weird behavior which looks like a rendering bug. The following minimal example produces it:

```js
var CT = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
CT.scale(24, 24);
CT.translate(1.0717, 0.1);
CT.rect(0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.1);
CT.rect(-0.05, -0.05, 0.1, 1);
CT.translate(0.4, 0);
CT.rect(-0.05, -0.05, 0.5, 1);
CT.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="50" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Looking at the resulting image I notice that the horizontal bar **interferes** with the left side vertical one, although it does not touch it. Changing the geometry (e.g. removing the right-side vertical bar), changes the artifacts in an (as far as I can see) unpredictable way.

[image]

Has anyone of you come across this issue? What could cause it and how to avoid it? This is annoying me more than it should. The behavior occurs in different browsers (I tested on IE11 and Firefox Quantum).

If it's not clear look at the **left most column of pixels on the left most rectangle**. The pixels pointed at the red arrow are darker than the pixels pointed at by the blue arrow even though the other 2 rectangles on the right seem like they should have absolutely no influence on the rectangle on the left.

[image]

Comment: It's really not clear what you're talking about. What do you mean, "interferes with"? When I run the code as posted right here, I see a thin rectangle on the left, a thicker one on the right, and a short horizontal rectangle protruding from the right-hand one. What did you expect instead?

Comment: If you look at where the thin rectangle would intersect the horizontal one if the horizontal one where longer, you'll see that the brightness/alpha are slightly different than above and below. The linked image shows it clearly.

Comment: [Bicubic Interpolation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poY_nGzEEWM)

Comment: 2D API  renders at sub pixel resolution. This can result in antialiasing artifacts.. To avoid draw at pixel boundaries eg `ctx.fillRect(0,0,10,10)` not `ctx.fillRect(0.5,0.5,1010)` @NiettheDarkAbsol this is not due to any interpolation, it is a anti aliasing artifact. Interpolation is used for image rendering and can be turned off.

Comment: @Blindman67 OP is specifically referring to the antialiased part of the thin rectangle, where it's ever so slightly darker where the protruding part on the thicker bar is. This does indeed cause the (default) bicubic interpolation curve to overshoot, because it doesn't work so well with massive changes (like straight-white to straight-black and back again).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the anomaly is too far from the other pixels to be affected by their values using bicubic interpolation.

Comment: @Blindman67 Clearly not, since the small protrusion is clearly affecting the exact values of the antialias.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The error is across the width of the canvas. If you draw a rectangle at 100 (approx 2400th pixel due to scale) it has the very same anomaly. It has nothing to do with bicubic (or any other) interpolation. It is due to anti aliasing error related to the low precision of GPU float

Comment: [Here's a smaller repo](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/bqd7fygt/)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to repo the issue in Edge but not Firefox 57.0.1 or Chrome 62. This might not be the fastest solution but it did fix the problem in Edge which is to rasterize each rectangle on it's own by calling `CT.fill` followed by `CT.beginPath` after each rectangle.

```js
var CT = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
CT.scale(24, 24);
CT.translate(1.0717, 0.1);
CT.rect(0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.1);
CT.fill();
CT.beginPath();
CT.rect(-0.05, -0.05, 0.1, 1);
CT.fill();
CT.beginPath();
CT.translate(0.4, 0);
CT.rect(-0.05, -0.05, 0.5, 1);
CT.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="50" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Honestly I'd file a bug. While I know the canvas spec is somewhat lenient it's hard to imagine this particular issue is spec compliant. (though it may be)

Comment: Of course. Thinking about it more they might say it's spec compliant though. Putting multiple lines, rectangles, curves, etc all in the same path the spec is probably pretty lenient on how that is rasterized. For a path with 2 rectangles this issue shown seems clear but I'm just guessing the algorithm is more concentrating on a path with 1000s of lines in the same path.

Comment: Well we'll see what they say. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422484 But actually I was wrong with my reset scale workaround, just completely messed up the scales...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a precision error in the floating point math used by the GPU.

Because you have zoomed into the rendering area 24 times normal the error is amplified.

There is not much you can do apart from rendering on pixel boundary and/or avoid very large scaling.

The image below rendered on FF. The canvas is top red box with zoomed in sections marked in red to show the anomalies. Was originally rendered on transparent cleared canvas, the white background was added in post.

Note that the effect can affect the width of the canvas.

Also note that some coordinates do not show the effect (columns marked with green arrows)

[image]

It does not happen on Chrome and I have not tried Edge.

Comment: If it doesn't happen on Chrome than is it really a GPU issue? Sounds like a Firefox/Edge issue.

Comment: @gman GPUs have selectable float precision and you can select lower precision in favor of performance. FF is a fast renderer, but I am puzzled as to the algorithmic cause. I have an example that I can not find at the moment that shows the same problem (even more pronounced vertical and horizontal) and its at least a year old.

Comment: What does GPU precision have to do with it? The rectangles seem unrelated. It shouldn't matter what precision.

Comment: @gman I am 99% sure it is a precision issue because as you move the x coord the error comes and goes which is typical of a precision problem.

Comment: It's certainly a precision issue. My point is it's unrelated to the GPU and instead related to whatever strange things those browsers are doing to render the 3 rectangles. Breaking them up by scanlines into more than just 3 rectangles or something else strange. In other words it's the browser introducing the precision issue, not the GPU